# Redux toolkit slices. How add new array correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

Let's imagine a server send us array. It can be the same or not. We don't know. How to add it correctly in slice?

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-state-new-array-4sswi?file=/src/redux/slices/slice.js

Like this?

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someSlice",
  initialState: {
    users: []
  },
  reducers: {
    actionSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.users = payload.users;
    }
  }
});
```

What if we get the same array? In this way actionSuccess will return like new array anyway! This means there will excess render.

So, my decision this way

```
const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someSlice",
  initialState: {
    users: []
  },
  reducers: {
    actionSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(state.users) !== JSON.stringify(payload.users)) {
        state.users = payload.users;
      }
      return state
    }
  }
});
```

But I think there is method better. What do u think?

Comment: the comparison should be done in your component, there's a way to prevent rendering if old array and new array are the same but the store should get the new array ether way

Answer (score 2):

I think let the redux-store get the data as it arrives from the server but use some of React's capabilities to memoize what you want.

I have forked your example and leverage `React.memo` in a `Dumb` component to show how if something new comes from the server, React will not render the `Dumb` component for old data because it's been memoized.

Here is the fork :-

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-state-new-array-forked-fgeym?file=/src/dumb.js

If you remove the `React.memo` bit, all the three list items will render again and again but otherwise, only the new item will render.

Check the **console logs**.

Note - shallow comparison by default. You can provide your custom comparison function to `React.memo` as second parameter.